# How to create a color with an alpha value using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In `UIKit` to create a color with an alpha value there are different ways, for example:

```
UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
```

but this method is not available on the corresponding class `Color` of `SwiftUI`.

What can I use?

Answer (score 87):

In `SwiftUI` there is one specific *modifier* called `opacity` that can be use to change the alpha level of any colors

```
Text("Hello world").background(Color.black.opacity(0.8)) // Set the background color as partially transparent.
```

Additionally the same modifier can be applied to any view, to change its alpha.

```
Image("myImage").opacity(0.8) //The image will be partially transparent
```

Comment: A small contribution to your answer: ```.opacity()```changes the opacity of any view. It just so happens that Color ***is*** a view. However, it is not needed to create a color with opacity, since it has its own parameter in the initialiser (check my answer for that).

Comment: Also: To be precise: Text("").background(Color.black.opacity(0.8)) does not "set the color to the background". What it is actually doing, is putting a view behind the text, that it just so happens to be one that paints a specific color. However, you could specify any view. For Example, try: Text("2222").background(Text("1111"))

Answer (score 27):

The color initializer has an opacity parameter:

```
Color(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.2)
```

Comment: This is the only answer that will change the opacity of a color and still have it remain a `Color` type. By adding `.opacity` modifier to a Color, it will return a `View` and not a `Color`. For example, you can't use, `.foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.8))` because you just changed the Color to a View.

Comment: Actually there is a ```.opacity``` modifier that returns a ```Color``` instead of a ```View```, I assume it has been added recently. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69451355/9439097) or [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/opacity(_:))

Answer (score 14):

It seems that now it is possible to use the `.opacity` method and still return a `Color` instead of a `View`:

###### [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/opacity(_:)):

```swift
func opacity(_ opacity: Double) -> Color
```

###### Example:

```swift
color.opacity(0.5)
```

Answer (score 13):

Apply the **opacity** modifier to any SwiftUI View like:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
    .fill(Color.yellow)
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    .opacity(0.5)
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't answer OP's question on how to create a color.  The opacity modifier is for a View

Answer (score 11):

Several answers here point to `.opacity()` method of View.  That covers the most common use cases, but perhaps what the OP wants to know is how to create a `Color` with transparency.

One is to use `Color` constructor that has the color space, components and opacity, as in the first example below.

If you already have a `Color` and want a translucent version of it, use the bridges to `UIColor` like the second example below

```
let transparentTeal = Color(.sRGB, red: 0.4, green: 1, blue: 0.1, opacity: 0.2)

let red = Color.red

let transparentRed = Color(UIColor(red).withAlphaComponent(0.3))
```