# How can I make a background in SwiftUI translucent?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I make the text background above the navigation bar translucent so that it looks like the text and navigation bar are the same object?

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("Test")
        .padding(.top, 9.5)
        .padding(.bottom, 8)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray) // I used a custom color set in the screenshot
        .font(.footnote)
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Text("Name")
            Text("Name")
            Text("Name")
        } .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

        .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading:
            Button("Cancel") {
                // self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            },
            trailing:
            Button("Done") {

            }.disabled(true)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a color with an alpha value using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822573/how-to-create-a-color-with-an-alpha-value-using-swiftui)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

SwiftUI's `Color` has an `opacity()` function that returns another `Color` with the given opacity. An opacity of 1.0 would be the same color, while an opacity of 0.0 would be completely clear.

For example, if you wanted to have the color be between completely opaque and completely clear, change:

```swift
Text("Test")
        .padding(.top, 9.5)
        .padding(.bottom, 8)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .font(.footnote)
```

To:

```swift
Text("Test")
        .padding(.top, 9.5)
        .padding(.bottom, 8)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5)) //Here is where we use the opacity
        .font(.footnote)
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color