# SwiftUI - the bottom sheet has an area which changes the background on contact with content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NWuh.gif)

There is a bottom sheet in the settings default app, in this bottom sheet there is a certain area with a button that changes the `background` when it comes into contact with `content` such as a `NavigationBar` or a `TabView`.  How can this be implemented?

I tried putting a button in toolbar on the bottom bar, it worked fine and close to what I wanted, but the area is too small. I also tried `.safeAreaInset` with `.bottomBar` placement , but how to make the `background` change from what is above the `content` and disappear when there is no `content` below it like in video .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to make the background opaque or blur it.

[The answers to this related question (the Opaque approach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805852/how-can-i-make-a-background-in-swiftui-translucent) may help you or you can try the answers [for this question on how to Blur the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610957/is-there-a-method-to-blur-a-background-in-swiftui).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.  I do not need a static blur background, I need a dynamic background that changes as I described above